# How to replace a existing column value with new column value in a table using self join in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the following TempTableA

```
Application     Id       Merchant
--------------------------------
201797838      331543     681
```

Actually the Id 331543 is not the correct Id for Merchant 681.

So I need to find the correct Id and then replace the existing Id.

Manually I will do the following to find the correct Id:

Firstly I will query for the following columns using the existing Id 331543 from table SchemeData like below

```
1. SchemeName 
2. TenureInMonths
3. ROI 
4. Approved 
5. IsSubvented
```

Query:

```
select SchemeName, TenureInMonths, ROI, Approved, IsSubvented  
from SchemeData 
where ID in (331543)
```

I will get the following output

```
SchemeName          TenureInMonths  ROI    Approved   IsSubvented
------------------------------------------------------------------
6 Mnths Vanilla        6             18       1          N
```

To find the correct Id, I will query like below:

```
 select Id 
 from SchemeData
 where SchemeName like '%6 Mnths Vanilla%' 
   and TenureInMonths = 6 
   and ROI = 18 
   and Approved = 1 
   and IsSubvented = 'N' 
   and Merchant = 681 
   and ID_EndDate >= GETDATE()
```

I will get the following Id for the corresponding Merchant 681

```
Id
-------
317122
```

Now I will replace the existing Id with the correct Id and my TempTableA will be like below

```
Application     Id       Merchant
--------------------------------
201797838      317122      681
```

Could you please help in finding the correct Id using SQL queries instead of doing it manually every time because there are lots of Id's to be replaced and it's taking a large amount of time.

Comment: That's av weired looking way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

I am thinking that this gets you the most recent merchant id according to your rules:

```
select s.*, s2.id as newid
from schemadata s cross apply
     (select top 1 s2.*
      from schemadata sd2
      where s2.SchemeName like '%' + s2.SchemeName + '%' and
            s2.TenureInMonths = s.TenureInMonths
            s2.ROI = s.ROI and
            s2.Approved = s.Approved and
            s2.IsSubvented = s.IsSubvented
            s2.Merchant = s.Merchant 
            s2.ID_EndDate >= GETDATE()
     ) s2;
```

If so, you can easily put this into an `update`:

```
update s
    set id = s2.id
from schemadata s cross apply
     (select top 1 s2.*
      from schemadata sd2
      where s2.SchemeName like '%' + s2.SchemeName + '%' and
            s2.TenureInMonths = s.TenureInMonths
            s2.ROI = s.ROI and
            s2.Approved = s.Approved and
            s2.IsSubvented = s.IsSubvented
            s2.Merchant = s.Merchant 
            s2.ID_EndDate >= GETDATE()
     ) s2;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon Linoff , here you have applied cross join with  the schemedata table.
But i need to join the TempTableA with the SchemeData Table . I tried the following query but it is not working as expected.

Comment: select Application, 
  (
 select top(1) S.Id from SchemeData S where S.SchemeName in (Select SchemeName from SchemeData where Id = B.Id and  
 S.TenureInMonths in ( Select TenureInMonths from SchemeData where Id = B.Id ) and   
 S.ROI in ( Select ROI from SchemeData where Id = B.Id ) and S.ApproSed =1 and   
S.MerchanId =  B.MerchanId and 
S.Id_EndDate >= GETDATE()  
) as Id,
Merchant
from  TempTableA  A Join TempTableA B on A.Application = B.Application